# Import .3ds models into JMonkeyEngine 3

Tags: java, opengl, blender, jmonkeyengine

There is a [wiki page](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme2%3amodel_loading?s%5b%5d=3ds) on **jmonkeyengine.org** about importing `.3ds` models into a scene, however the article is 3 years old and does no longer apply to JME3. Is it still possible? Is there some library for download that can be included to do this?

If not, I will have to convert manually all my files with Blender...

** **Update** **

I dropped Blender and I have asked a friend to create the models in 3D Studio Max (3D modeling is really not my cup of tea after all) and he's struggling exporting the skeleton of the animated body to OgreXML format; the `.skeleton.xml` file is just not there!

I don't know how the ogre model (with animations and all) was created, but an up to date, detailed, tutorial from 3DS to displaying the model in a JME application would be nice. If anyone know where I can find one? It seems so easy in the forums, but we are unable to replicate the process with our own models.

Comment: I'm sad to see this question unanswered, since I'm facing the exact same problem. If you find anything out, let me know! :)

Comment: I will ask around in the JME forum when I'm done with other issues (with TerrainGrid), but even the blender importer no longer works with Blender 2.6+. It seems that the "preferred" way of doing things is to export models to OgreXML format, then convert it into j3o... but it all seems counter productive to me, anyway. If I find anything, of course I will update this question :)

Comment: Cross posted: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26761/import-3ds-into-jmonkeyengine-3

Comment: Interesting that this was closed as off topic, but yet still get me a "Popular question" badge. * poker face *

Answer (score 0):

Link to wiki page is dead, but I believe that was possible in JME2.

In JME3 you should export in .obj file or like this (but this method didn't worked for me): http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/sdk:3ds_to_blender_to_jmp?s[]=import&s[]=3ds

Comment: Right now, we need to export our 3ds files (which contains animations) to OgreXML, but we still have problem with the process (exporting the `skeleton.xml` file) I know about Wavefront .obj format, but we had problems with face orientations (something about normals) and it does not support animations, so we ended up trying to use OgreXML, which is probably the favored way of importing models in JME3 as far as I can tell.